# Pandas - counting frequency of value for each value type in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So the data looks like this:

```
type value
A    0
A    6
B    5
C    0
A    3
C    0
```

I want to get the number of zeros in *value* column for each type in *type* column. Preferably in a new dataframe. So it would look like this:

```
type zero_count
A    1
B    0
C    2
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: `groupby` and `sum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare column by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==`, convert to integers `0/1` by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) or [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) and then aggregate by column `df['type']` with `sum`:

```
df1 = df['value'].eq(0).view('i1').groupby(df['type']).sum().reset_index(name='zero_count')
```

```
df1 = df['value'].eq(0).astype(int).groupby(df['type']).sum().reset_index(name='zero_count')
```

---

```
print (df1)
  type  zero_count
0    A           1
1    B           0
2    C           2
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for